# Cloning command `script` and PTY background job problems: terminal messed up

Tags: c, macos, unix

I'm trying to recode the UNIX command `script` (as it is on OSX). This is part of an exercise for school to help students learn UNIX APIs. We are only allowed to use system calls, more specifically, only those available on MAN(2) pages on Mac OSX (since that's our OS at school).

I have a 'first version' that kind of works. Running a program such as `ls` prints the right output to the screen and in an output file.

**The problem scenario**

I run `bash` from within the `script`-clone. First issue is I get the following error:

`bash: no job control in this shell`

I have tried forcing the `bash` process into foreground with `setpgrp` and `setpgid` but that din't change anything so I concluded that was not the problem.

I also tried to understand why the real `script` command uses `cfmakeraw` (at least on Linux), as seen [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/b0d6b85720f6176837afef60ca5c199d5a391c82/term-utils/script.c#L520), but I don't get it. The MAN page is not very helpful.

The real `script` also `dup2`s STDIN on the `slave`, as seen [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/b0d6b85720f6176837afef60ca5c199d5a391c82/term-utils/script.c#L474), but when I do that, it seems like input isn't read anymore.

However, the bash still runs, and I can execute commands inside of it.

But if I run `vim` inside it, and then hit Ctrl-Z to put `vim` to the background, the terminal is messed up (which does not happen when I'm in my regular terminal).

So I guess I must have done something wrong. I'd appreciate any advice/help.

---

Here's the source code:
https://github.com/conradkleinespel/unix-command-script/tree/2587b07e7a36dc74bf6dff0e82c9fdd33cb40411

You can compile by doing: `make` (it builds on OSX 10.9, hopefully on Linux as well)

And run by doing: `./ft_script`

*Don't know it it makes more sense to have all the source code in StackOverflow as it would crowd the page with it. If needed, I can replace the Git link with the source.*

Comment: I"m not sure a non-osx `script` would do any better with a `ctrl-Z'd vim`. Otherwise, I don't have much to offer on this question. Good luck!

Comment: Well, the original OSX `script` handles the ctrl-z'd vim just fine. So it must be possible somehow. It's just that I'm not proficient enough to understand the original sources especially since there arent always a lot if comments.

Comment: You could run `script` with `truss` or `strace` or whatever tracing utilities are available and compare with a `trace` of your `ft_script` for the same seq. You may also find that `script` is taking into account values found in various env vars, `$COLUMNS, $LINES`, `stty` settings or somehow communicating or monitoring activity of the display sub-systems. Finally, you could compile the true `script` code for debugging (your code too), and use dbx to step thru your basic problems.  Now I'm really out of ideas (and those have high probabilities of being false paths to search :-/ ). Good luck.

Comment: As far as I can tell your `script` fails to tell the shell that invoked it that it should stop interpreting input as terminal input and forward everything to your `script` including signals, special characters, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use OS X, so I can't directly test your code, but I'm currently writing a toy terminal emulator and had similar troubles.

**about "bash: no job control in this shell"**

In order to perform job control, a shell needs to be a *session leader* and the *controlling process* of its terminal. By default, your program inherits the controlling terminal of your own shell which runs your `script` program and which is also a session leader. Here is how to make your new slave process a session leader after `fork`:

```
/* we don't need the inherited master fd */
close(master);
/* discard the previous controlling tty */
ioctl(0, TIOCNOTTY, 0);
/* replace existing stdin/out/err with the slave pts */
dup2(slave, 0);
dup2(slave, 1);
dup2(slave, 2);
/* discard the extra file descriptor for the slave pts */
close(slave);
/* make the pts our controlling terminal */
ioctl(0, TIOCSCTTY, 0);
/* make a new session */
setsid()
```

At this point, the forked process has stdin/out/err bound to the new pts, the pts became its controlling terminal, and the process is a session leader. The job control should now work.

**about raw tty**

When you run a program inside a normal terminal, it looks like this:

```
(term emulator, master side) <=> /dev/pts/42 <=> (program, slave side)
```

If you press `^Z`, the terminal emulator will write the ascii character `0x1A` to the pts. It is a control character, so it won't be sent to the program, but instead the kernel will issue `SIGSTP` to the program and suspend it. The process of transforming characters into something else is called "line cooking" and has various settings that can be adjusted for each tty.

Now let's look at the situation with `script`:

```
term emulator <=> /dev/pts/42 <=> script <=> /dev/pts/43 <=> program
```

With normal line settings, what happens when you press `^Z`? It will be transformed into `SIGSTP` by `/dev/pts/42` and `script` will be suspended. But that's not what we want, instead we'd like the `0x1A` character produced by our `^Z` to go as-is through `/dev/pts/42`, then be passed by `script` to `/dev/pts/43` and only then be transformed into `SIGSTP` to suspend the program.

This is the reason why the pts between your terminal and script must be configured as "raw", so that all control characters reach the pts between `script` and the program, as if you were directly working with it.